# SignalR Content Specific Notifications

Tags: javascript, asp.net, notifications, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am using SignalR for notifications in my web site but i couldn't find a way to send notifications according to the page/content.

Let me explain in details.
Assume that, there is a page for showing a record from database (for example a blog post).
So there is only one page for showing posts as it should be.
And every post has a like counter which i want to update via signalr notifications, if another user clicks like button. Until here, it is very easy to accomplish.
This page contains a javascript code block like below

```
var notify = $.connection.notificationHub;           

notify.client.updatePostLikeCount = function (likeCount) {
     $("#likeCount").text(likeCount);
};
```

And this function triggered from server-side like below (it is in another class instead of Hub class)

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
context.Clients.User(user.Id).updatePostLikeCount(likeCount);
```

But a user might open more than one post; so if a notification is sent from server-side all opened tabs receive this notification and update its counter.

I looked for .Caller method but it is not available in IHubContext interface which GetHubContext() returns and couldn't find another way.

To summarize, i want to send notifications to users who had opened the post which user liked.

**EDIT:** After sending question i got an idea. Continue sending notification as being and filtering according to the content at client side. It is not very good but i think it will work with charms.